# Detecting a retina display iPad with javascript

Tags: javascript, ipad, retina-display, device-detection

I'm having a problem detecting a retina iPad (and similar devices) using just `screen.availWidth` and `window.devicePixelRatio`. The problem is that iPhones and iPads give the number of dips for `screen.availWidth` whereas android devices seem to report the number of physical pixels so I can't reliably do `screen.availWidth / window.devicePixelRatio` to calculate if the screen is of a tablet size.

Is there some other DOM property I can use to help me?

*edit* - To sum up in a way which hopefully makes clear that the question isn't a duplicate

How can I tell if `screen.availWidth` reports a value that has already been adjusted to take account of `window.devicePixelRatio`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if iPhone has retina display or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016339/how-to-detect-if-iphone-has-retina-display-or-not)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor not exactly - `devicePixelRatio` reliably tells you whether it's a retina display, but doesn't necessarily tell you how many dips you have to work with

Comment: You can combine with detecting User Agent, which by default browser is telling you the device model

Comment: @Shivan_Raptor ... but this isn't future-proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but here's an approach I think might work. I'll do a jsbin for it when I get time.

Because all devices (to the best of my knowledge) adjust for devicePixelRatio before passing the value to CSS media queries we can (in slightly pseudo code)

1. measure `window.devicePixelRatio` and `screen.availWidth`
2. Write a style tag to the head which includes a media query something like the following

   ```
   #my-test-el {
     display: none;
     visibility: visible;
   }

   @media screen and (min-device-width:screen.availWidth) {
     #my-test-el {
    visibility: hidden;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Append `<div id="my-test-el">` to the page
4. Read off the `style.visibility` attribute. If it equals hidden then the css value is the same value as screen.availWidth => screen.availWidth has been preadjusted for dpr.

*edit* It works! http://jsbin.com/IzEYuCI/3/edit. I'll put together a modernizr plugin too

*edit* And here's the pull request to get it in Modernizr - https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/1139. please upvote if you'd find it useful

Comment: For everyone reading this, the solution falsely identifies zoomed in browsers as highDPI/retina and does not identify a retina which is zoomed out equal or more than the "retina scale".

Answer (score 4):

That should help

```
var retina = (window.retina || window.devicePixelRatio > 1);
```

**UPDATE**

```
Retina.isRetina = function(){
    var mediaQuery = "(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),\
                      (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),\
                      (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),\
                      (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)";

    if (root.devicePixelRatio > 1)
      return true;

    if (root.matchMedia && root.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches)
      return true;

    return false;
};
```

Comment: It's not detecting that there's a retina display that's the problem, it's detecting that there is a retina display of a certain size or above

Comment: Pardon me but what is retina display it's higher pixel density  display. So if the ratio is higher than 1  what it means "if it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck and walks like a duck - then it is probably a duck"
Check my update straight from retinajs detection

Comment: The problem isn't detecting if the display is retina it's knowing if the device adjusts screen.availWidth itself or if you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) plugin may help : [Modernizr Retina : HiDPI Test](https://github.com/benlister/utilities/tree/master/Modernizr%20Retina%20%3a%20HiDPI%20test)

*Note:* Requires Modernizr's Media Queries feature

Comment: Reports true if the user have zoomed in more than 30% on a non-retina display.

Comment: the utility has not been updated for few years. You might need to contact the developer for help.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. This was just a comment for others reading this, to know the limitations. I have not found any way to do a proper detection but the plugin could be improved to make a better guess.